# Dynamics AX 4 issue with x++ email attachment

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, axapta, email-attachments, x++

I want to send emails with attachment but I'm using AX V4 which is a 32 bits version and my office version is 64 bits so I can't use integrated email attachment with reportSendMail() method of Info class, I'm using the following code with sysemailbatch and sysinetMail classes:

```
sysemailbatch.parmAttachmentfileName(filename); //filename with path in UNC    

SysInetMail::sendEMail('01', 'fr', ToAddress, mappings, FromAddress, '\\\\UNC_path\MyAttachment.csv');
```

Both are working, I'm receiving the mail but no attachment, no error message
I also tried email queue with sysemailTable methods, same thing, I receive mail without attachment

I'm using AX V4 SP1 on TSE servers in W2016. I allowed attachments from a specific path in Administration/Setup/email parameters

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this post 8 years ago for 2009, but I think it still applies. I think I recall the Outlook piece being too problematic (server-side, client-side, 32-bit, 64-bit, mail profiles, etc) that I just bypassed it and made this post below.

And for years after I've been at various customers and I find this same code and laugh a little, so others bypassed it too. See if you can use it in AX 4.0 or if you can adapt it.

https://www.alexondax.com/2012/01/how-to-send-emails-from-ax-without.html

Then you can use the `reportSendMail()` method and your users can too.

Comment: Thanks Alex but it doesn't solve my problem, my emails are not sent, i debugged your code and found nothing, nothing just happens, no error, the code stops after   mymail.Send(mailmessage);

Comment: @ThomasPost have you verified your `SMTP` settings are valid and work via Telnet or something? Under `SystemAdmin>Setup>System>E-mail parameters`.

Comment: My smtp settings seems correct because i have no problem to send mails with alerts or x++

Comment: The code should work, but you could verify your SMTP settings via Telnet/job but I think you should try debugging a little more to see why nothing happens. It's just using `.NET` classes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage?view=net-5.0 for example.